# Is there a way to do 'print screen' capturing areas off screen?

Tags: windows, community-faq-proposed, print-screen

Sometimes I like to get a screen grab of a web page or application so that I can edit it for UI design purposes. Is there a way of getting a screen grab of the entire page (including ares which you'd have to scroll down in order to see) so I don't have to do two or more screen grabs and stitch them together?

Comment: duplicate from http://superuser.com/questions/254/screenshot-utilities-for-windows and http://superuser.com/questions/254/screenshot-utilities-for-windows

Comment: Not duplicate unless those capture HTML generated beyond a browser window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For web pages there is a great add on called [Screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146)! that allows you to capture an entire portion of a web page. I use it all the time for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

Try http://aviary.com/launch/talon.  You'll have to set it at high quality if you're doing any kind of graphics work.  If you have to log in somewhere or you're accessing something on an intranet, it probably won't work.

---

Here's another one that installs locally: [Fireshot](http://screenshot-program.com/fireshot/).  It works for Firefox and IE.  Here's a sample screenshot of SuperUser, click for hi-res:

[image]

Comment: +1 for FireShot. I'd say Talon is overkill, though, unless you use the Aviary suite.

Comment: +1 for fireshot... please list separate suggestions, well, separately, so they get voted on appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The [free version of FastStone Capture](http://www.aplusfreeware.com/categories/mmedia/FastStoneCapture.html) will do this.

See answer to this question - [What’s the best *Free* alternative to SnagIt (Screenshot capture program)?](https://superuser.com/questions/16954/whats-the-best-free-alternative-to-snagit-screenshot-capture-program/17391#17391).

Comment: This just scrolls the window and then captures the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I use FastStone Capture all the time and I really like it, but I can't seem to use it in Linux and wonder if there is an alternative as I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score -1):

This question is a duplicate of both:

- [Screenshot utilities for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/254/screenshot-utilities-for-windows)
- [What’s the best *Free* alternative to SnagIt (Screenshot capture program)?](https://superuser.com/questions/16954/whats-the-best-free-alternative-to-snagit-screenshot-capture-program-close)

### Best answers:

[Snipping Tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipping_Tool) for Vista and Windows 7

[image]

---

[Cropper](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=cropper&DownloadId=8026).

[image: Cropper]

or

[Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.asp) (not free!)

[image]

Comment: Its not a "duplicate" ... those other questions do not particularly enquire about off-screen images.

Comment: And that makes my answers bad?

Comment: actually, it does, Snipping tool didn't work for me because I can't scroll during the snipping