# How to save a web page as an image (jpg, png, etc) in IE9?

Tags: images, internet-explorer-9

I used to be able to use the IE7 Pro plug-in for IE8 and IE7 to save the entire web page as an image, but this plug-in is no longer supported by IE9.  Now I have to find an alternative.

How can I do this in IE9? Are there any IE9-compatible plug-ins that can do this?  I can't use print screen for this because that only captures the window itself and not content that must be scrolled to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to do 'print screen' capturing areas off screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/17939/is-there-a-way-to-do-print-screen-capturing-areas-off-screen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just confirmed [DuckLink Capture](http://www.ducklink.com/p/free-screen-capture-tool/)'s "scrolling" mode captures the entire length of a web page in IE9:

> **Capture a Tall Web Page**
>   (Windows Only, Mac OS Coming Soon)
>
> Can’t fit it on the screen? DuckCapture auto-scrolls the web page or
>   window and grabs it all!

Comment: I tried it and it works just fine, so thank you.  I wish it weren't so slow, tho.  IE7 Pro's save function was instantaneous, but DuckLink works with other windows, not just IE9, so that's a fair trade-off.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: it's not instant, but there is an advanced option to set the time interval for scrolling pages to 0 milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an ugly solution, it "Prints" document into JPG file.
http://www.print-driver.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

Is IE a mandatory requirement? If not you can use Firefox and [Screengrab Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab/).

Answer (score 0):

...or you could use [Screen Capture by Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capture-by-google/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg#detail/screen-capture-by-google/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg) Google Chrome. I use this to capture a region or the whole screen.

Comment: The OP is using IE9, not Chrome.